# Best way to put functions python

Tags: python, function

I bring a few days working on python coming from Matlab and I have the next doubt:

I had a matlab program with a lot of functions defined at the end of my m-file. Matlab recognizes those functions even if I call them at the beginning and they are defined at the bottom of my code.

Now, with python, I don't know what is the best way to put the functions because python needs to know the definition of the functions before calling them.
I don't want to create a new file for each function. 
I would like to put all functions together but I can't figure it out.
I hope you can help me.

Thx,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way you can have all the functions is to add a function that does everything you want it to do:

```
def main():
    #do stuff
    f()
    g()
    ...
```

And add this to the end of the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will only execute if your file is the main file. If you import your file from another file, then it won't execute all the code in main().

Comment: I'd prefer this method, just because it doesn't needlessly create other files. You can always refactor functions out later if you need to share them between modules.

Comment: I like this way and it works nicely too. Thx. For me, now it's more like matlab style because I have the main code on top and the functions at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the functions in a functions.py and include it in every document

```
import functions
```

then you can call a function by adding the prefix `functions.`

Comment: Easier than expected! Exactly using: from functions import *   Thx!

Comment: @tete you should shy away from using `from functions import *` as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/1980029.

Comment: @tete, if you don't want to call all functions (mentioned by @robjohncox), you can do a from `functions import function1`. That is recommended and it is used a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Actually python does not need you to declare functions in any particular order to have them called.

For example this works fine :

```
def a():
  return b()

def b():
  return 1

a()
```

Comment: That's true but I don't like to have the functions at the top of the code. Thx.

Comment: It's also important to note that Python throws an exception if you have the call to `a()` above the definition of `b()`.